# insert data in table of sqlite database in background

Tags: iphone

I need inserting data in table in background.I am using `NSTimer` for inserting data in table of sqlite database.But It freeze the application during the inserting process.I also used `NSThread` but It also create same problem. I am sharing code which I am using:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(InsertDataInTable) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)InsertDataInTempTable
{
        DatabaseManager *objDb=[[DatabaseManager alloc]init];
        [objDb setDelegate:self];
        for(int i=0;i<[arrayTempTableData count];i++)
        {
            [objDb savedata:[dictCurrentUrlInfo objectForKey:TempTableName] elements:[arrayTempTableData objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Save Operation

-(void)savedata:(NSString *)into elements:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictInsert{
        NSString *sql_String = @"";
        if([into isEqualToString:TABLEFirstAidTemp])
        {
            sql_String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ VALUES('%@', '%@', '%@')", into,[dictInsert objectForKey:@"ArticleNumber"],[dictInsert objectForKey:@"ArticleTitle"],[dictInsert objectForKey:@"ArticleCategory"]];
        }
        sqlite3_exec(sql_Database1, [sql_String UTF8String], nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Please provide me a proper solution to get rid of this problem.I want to perform inserting data in table in background. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a NSThread. Maybe you implemented it wrong.

Your code will look like this

```
-(void)InsertDataInTempTable
{
       [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(InsertingData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)InsertingData
{
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        DatabaseManager *objDb=[[DatabaseManager alloc]init];
        [objDb setDelegate:self];
        for(int i=0;i<[arrayTempTableData count];i++)
        {
            [objDb savedata:[dictCurrentUrlInfo objectForKey:TempTableName] elements:[arrayTempTableData objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        [pool release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Save Operation

-(void)savedata:(NSString *)into elements:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictInsert{
        NSString *sql_String = @"";
        if([into isEqualToString:TABLEFirstAidTemp])
        {
            sql_String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ VALUES('%@', '%@', '%@')", into,[dictInsert objectForKey:@"ArticleNumber"],[dictInsert objectForKey:@"ArticleTitle"],[dictInsert objectForKey:@"ArticleCategory"]];
        }
        sqlite3_exec(sql_Database1, [sql_String UTF8String], nil, nil, nil);
}
```